# Location of cache validity bit

Tags: cpu, cpu-cache

Not sure if this is even the right site to ask for, but I'm quite clueless regarding any possible web research for this, so I thought to ask here, and maybe someone know the answer.
Studying how a cache is made, I've learned that it's divided in blocks, every blcok is, for example, made of 32 bytes. Then I've learned that every block of the cache, corrisponds to a block of RAM, (making it easy), and the CPU, when it comes to check if the block is the right one, uses some bits, 1 is called the validity bit, and the others are the tag bits, and they should be the most valuated bit. I've been told that these bits are not part of the block where the data is stored, and here we come, where are they? Where are they located in the cache?

Thanks everybody for answering.

P.S. I know for sure it's not an hamster choosing the right ones, woulld have been cool though :/

Comment: They will be wherever the chip designers wanted them to be, most likely in some extra storage along-side the corresponding cache-line. However, where they are is mostly irrelevant because they're only used for internal cache book-keeping and almost definitely not visible to you.

Comment: Ahaha yeah that's freaking true!

Comment: Thanks man :) really, my mind is blown up cause tomorrow I've an exam and I'm really tired